# How to UIActivityViewController excluded items dynamic based on a changing array?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uiactivityviewcontroller

I went through a tutorial for implementing the `UIActivityViewController` everything is working as expected. I can also use `excludedItems` property to remove any default options in `UIActivityViewController`. But now I want to make this code more dynamic. Actually my plan is that user can choose which options he can choose to omit or exclude from the `UIActivityViewController` . So for that I am planning to pass an array with some fixed keys and based on that keys I can define which items to included in excluded lists. Below is the sample code :

```
NSArray* excludedArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Facebook", nil];
UIActivityViewController *controller = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]initWithActivityItems:items applicationActivities:nil];
if ( [excludedArray containsObject: @"Facebook"] ) {
    NSArray *excluded = @[UIActivityTypeMessage];
    controller.excludedActivityTypes = excluded;
}
```

Right now `excludedArray` only contains `message` string so based on that I added the `UIActivityTypeMessage` to `excluded` array . But tomorrow if the user adds more item to `excludedArray` for example `print` then based on that I must be able to add `UIActivityTypePrint` to `excluded` array. How to achieve that?

Comment: Could you explain your question please? You have an activity controller and you have a list of excluded activities that you succeeded to exclude. What's the problem?

Comment: problem is for determining these excluded activities I will be passing as a dynamic array . Some times this array will only contain "message" string, so based on this string I will exclude copy option using UIActivityTypeMessage . But some times this array will contain "message", "print"  string. so I will check this string and based on that I will add corresponding excluded items UIActivityTypePrint and UIActivityTypeMessage. How can I do it?  I achieved using static array but for dynamic array I have no idea

Comment: What do you mean by the "dynamic array" problem? Do you want to update the activity controller if the array is changed while the controller is still presented, or what?

Comment: not while presented. I want to update the Activity Controller options like copy, message etc based on the dynamic array before presenting the activity controller. for example if the array contains "print" string then I will exclude print option from UIActivity controller similarly if the array contains "print" and "message" string  then I will exclude Message and Print option from Activity controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Link UIActivityType enum values with the selection you'll give to user using switch case.
- On select/deselect update the array.
- At last pass the enum array to **excludedActivityTypes**.

  ```
    func getExcludedActivityTypes(stringArray: [String]) -> [UIActivity.ActivityType]{
    var excludeArray: [UIActivity.ActivityType] = []
    for str in stringArray
    {
        switch str
        { 
        case "messaging":
            excludeArray.append(.message)
            break
        case "postToTwitter":
            excludeArray.append(.postToTwitter)
            break

            // write others to exclude those types
        default:
            break
        }
    }

    return excludeArray}
  ```

Objective c - Alternative(you can use if else statement as objective c doesn't support strings for switch cases)

```
-(NSArray<UIActivityType>*)getExcludedActivityTypes:(NSArray<NSString*>*)stringArray {
NSMutableArray<UIActivityType> * excludeArray = @[].mutableCopy;

for(NSString * str in stringArray) {
    if([str isEqualToString:@"messaging"]){
        [excludeArray addObject:UIActivityTypeMessage];
    }
    
    else if([str isEqualToString:@"postToTwitter"]){
        [excludeArray addObject:UIActivityTypePostToTwitter];
    }
    // write others to exclude those types
}
return excludeArray;}
```

Comment: can you explain the first point clearly?

Comment: create dynamic array of `@property (nullable, nonatomic, strong) NSArray<UIActivityType> *excludedActivityTypes;`, for example pass constant string array to a function -> map enum values with constant strings using switch case or `containsObject` and return the array of `UIActivityType`, according to that array you can exclude those types.

Comment: Thanks can you explain with code wise?

Comment: thanks but this is in swift code. Actually I am new to objective C so in objective c I have doubt. Please post objective c alternative